# How to convert Hibernate HQL into Hibernate Criteria

Tags: sql, join, hql

How to convert the following Query to Criteria. Please help

```
select   * FROM TT_TASK task_table INNER JOIN TT_DEPARTMENT_INFO ON TT_DEPARTMENT_INFO.DEPARTMENT_ID = task_table.DEPARTMENT where task_table.CONTENT_TYPE='Video';
```

I want to to select only those Tasks that have content type `Video` and also Department Info from `TT_DEPARTMENT_INFO` for only those records that are selected by first query i.e that has content type video

**Update**

Two cases

1) There is no mapping at all

2) PK and FK relationship between DEPARTMENT_ID and DEPARTMENT

Comment: how can someone help you if you don't put the mapping...

Comment: There is no mapping, I also updated the question. Thnx for pointing it out

Comment: you use nhibernate without entity mapping? and that is an hql query?

Comment: No There is mapping but there is not PK FK relationship.